# How to get the Site Id of SharePoint using Graph SharePoint Explorer

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

How to get the Microsoft SharePoint SiteID using Microsoft Graph API Explorer.

Initially i tried with below API i able to get the Site ID

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/tenantName.sharepoint.com:/sites/TestSite:/drives?select=name,id
```

Sharepoint URL:

```
https://tenantName.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite
```

I output i got is:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives",
"value": [
    {
        "id": "b!l17-JY9YT67Qp-2TBvsUupBLMUF2SrJHp5VylCDZThT7HpCdF-7uQ6NTp6t-MbR5",
        "name": "Documents"
    }
]
```

}

But, when i try with Communication Site

Whose SharePoint URL is:

```
https://tenantName.sharepoint.com/SitePages/DevHome.aspx
```

Graph Explorer API

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/tenantName.sharepoint.com:/SitePages/DevHome:/drives?select=name,id
```

I am getting below error:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "itemNotFound",
    "message": "The provided path does not exist, or does not represent a site",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "8329dfca-c63b-4af5-80b8-75f26be9e2e8",
        "date": "2019-10-31T13:18:33"
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`sitePage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sitepage?view=graph-rest-beta) is a fundamentally different resource than a [`site`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/site?view=graph-rest-1.0).

- A `site` is a container that owns any number of sub-sites, apps, lists, document libraries, etc.
- A `sitePage` is just another resource owned by a `site`.
- The `sitePage` resource is currently only available in the Microsoft Graph Beta version.

So the query for `/SitePages/DevHome.aspx` would be:

```
/beta/sites/root/pages/{pageId}
```

If you don't yet know the correct `id` for the page, you can filter the `SitePage` collection based on the page's name:

```
/beta/sites/root/pages?$filter=name eq 'DevHome.aspx'
```

This will return a collection with a single entity (the `DevHome.aspx` page):

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#sites('root')/pages",
    "value": [
        {
            "eTag": "",
            "id": "{id}",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2014-07-10T05:47:29Z",
            "name": "DevHome.aspx",
            "webUrl": "SitePages/DevHome.aspx",
            "createdBy": {
                "user": {
                    "displayName": "System Account"
                }
            },
            "lastModifiedBy": {
                "user": {
                    "displayName": "System Account"
                }
            },
            "parentReference": {
                "siteId": "{id}"
            },
            "contentType": {
                "id": "0x0101080062C83F3CFED6744A882F729480DE6C17",
                "name": "Wiki Page"
            },
            "webParts": [],
            "publishingState": {
                "level": "published",
                "versionId": "1.0"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I should also point out that you're misinterpreting the result of your first query. When you request `/v1.0/sites/{tenant}:/{path}:/drives?select=name,id`, you are not getting the IDs for each `Site`, you're getting the IDs for each `Drive` within that `Site`. You can find the objects contained within a site in the [Relationships section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/site?view=graph-rest-1.0#relationships) of the Site Resource documentation

Comment: Hi Sir,
I tried with beta i am still getting an error.
Below is my correct api which i am trying in Graph API: 
Am i trying with correct api: https://XXXXXX.sharepoint.com/beta/sites/root/pages?$filter='DevHome.aspx' ?

Comment: That isn't the correct `$filter` clause. It should be `?$filter=name eq 'DevHome.aspx'`.

Answer (score -3):

Your Graph API call is incorrect.
Try this one :
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/tenantName.sharepoint.com?select=name,id